# pandas most efficient way to execute arithmetic operations on multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

my first post!
I'm running python 3.8.5 & pandas 1.1.0 on jupyter notebooks.

I want to divide several columns by the corresponding elements in another column of the same dataframe.
For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 4], 'b': [4, 6, 8], 'c':[6, 9, 12]})
df
```

```
    a   b   c
0   2   4   6
1   3   6   9
2   4   8   12
```

I'd like to divide columns 'b' & 'c' by the corresponding values in 'a' and substitute the values in 'b' and 'c' with the result of this division. So the above dataframe becomes:

```
    a   b   c
0   2   2   3
1   3   2   3
2   4   2   3
```

I tried

```py
df.iloc[: , 1:] = df.iloc[: , 1:] / df['a']
```

but this gives:

```
    a   b   c
0   2   NaN NaN
1   3   NaN NaN
2   4   NaN NaN
```

I got it working by doing:

```py
for colname in df.columns[1:]:
    df[colname] = (df[colname] / df['a'])
```

Is there a faster way of doing the above by avoiding the for loop?

thanks,
mk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, use [div](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with `axis=0`:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].div(df.a, axis=0)
```

Comment: edited it, as the OP wants division, not subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.b= df.b/df.a
df.c=df.c/df.a
```

or

```
df[['b','c']]=df.apply(lambda x: x[['b','c']]/x.a ,axis=1)
```